# How to investigate what is in the Meteor appCache

Tags: meteor, html5-appcache

I recently added the Meteor `appcache` package and since I had the following error message:

```
** You are using the appcache package but the total size of the
** cached resources is 7.6MB.
**
** This is over the recommended maximum of 5 MB and may break your
** app in some browsers! See http://docs.meteor.com/#appcache
** for more information and fixes.
```

It is hard to believe that my scripts have that size, and my `/public` is completely empty. In Firefox I went to `about:cache` and looked at the `appcache` - but I only saw my script files there, though it might have included outdated versions of the same file. [Searching for `localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js` yielded two results, with different IDs.] No script file was bigger than 200KB so I can hardly imagine reaching 7.6MB.

Is this only development related and if not, how else can I see what Meteor is putting in the appcache to reach this size?

Comment: The appcache package is currently somewhat broken, you might find this reading of interest : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/tFXZkhIWeKk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In production, the appcache will be smaller.

You can view the appcache for an individual page in Chrome by going to View > Developer > Developer Tools, then Resources > Application Cache. (`about:cache` in Firefox appears to show the cache for all sites.)

These are my findings:

- When I run my site during development, the largest file is jQuery which takes up 1.2 MB (a bit odd considering the unminified jQuery is only about 250k).
- When I run my site in production (using `meteor run --production` or deploying the site for real), the largest file is a single 756k JavaScript file. This leaves plenty of room for images and such.